# Different Layouts for Log Levels in Log4j

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j

I am using Log4j and I want to log with different log levels.
It would be nice, if I could use a custom Layout for every Log Level, or just have one logger that logs only the log message without any formatting.
I don't really know how to do that, so I would be glad if any of you guys could give me some hints about it.

Here's my log4j.properties:

```
# Root Logger
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, console, file

# Appender to Console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] - %m%n

# Appender to Log-File
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Append=false
log4j.appender.file.File=adsync.log

log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %m%n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its easy to implement a new Layout according to your requirement. You can either extend any of the existing layout or create a new one itself.

You then write your own implementation of format(LoggingEvent event) in LayOut, At this point you get to know the log level from the LoggingEvent and change the format accordingly.